# CDI bean configuration

Tags: spring, cdi

I'm totally new to CDI.

I'm used at configuring beans in XML (Spring). In CDI, should I configure them in classes directly? I have tens of beans with the same implementation but different configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, configuration happens within the code.  There have been several attempts at doing XML based configuration, look for Seam Config.

For your tens of beans, you would typically use producer methods to create the individual implementations with their own configuration.  CDI uses qualifiers, rather than bean ids to identify beans.

Answer (score 4):

CDI uses a mixture of annotations and xml configuration to configure which beans are active in the deployment. It's a big topic but I'll attempt to summarise:

On your bean implementations you can use the following standard annotations:

```
@Default
@Alterative
@Vetoed
@Specializes
```

@Default is assumed unless no other annotations are present

@Alternative beans are not active unless specified so in your META-INF/beans.xml

@Vetoed beans are never considered active

@Specializes beans will always take precedence over their superclasses.

In addition to those you can create your own qualifiers to more accurately select which bean you want for what purpose.

You would create a qualifier as an annotation like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER, METHOD })
public @interface MyQualifier {
}
```

Note the @Qualifier and @Retention(RUNTIME) annotations.
You can also add parameters to your customer qualifier.

I would recommend giving the Weld documentation a read, it's comprehensive and quite well written:

[Weld manual](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/2.3.0.Final/en-US/html/)